# Highcharts Graph : Spline updating each second needs a pause button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am referring to this chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

For us we need to display this chart and at the same time needs to provide a pause button to pause the graph. Any idea/help/suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return from updating event in case of some flag (checkbox in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/FEE2J/)) setted up:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#pause:checked').length>0) return;
    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.random();
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}, 1000);
```

please note, that sample uses timeline to make a points, so pause will not stop time,

---

you may also like

```
setInterval(function() {
  var flag=true;
  if ($('#pause:checked').length>0) flag=false;;
  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
      y = Math.random();
  series.addPoint([x, y], flag, flag);
}, 1000);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/FEE2J/3/) , this will continue to update chart, but not scroll to the last position